# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.my_theme').(APT0000)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-theme

I recently installed Xamarin Android brand new (version 5.10.1 build 6).  When I tried to add a theme, I got the dreaded "No resource found..." error.
It is the first theme I have tried to add, so I am not sure if the problem could be due to something I've written in my code.
Searching on StackOverflow and the Xamarin fora however, I discovered that the issue probably means that some Android library is not installed.

So I have installed a lot more stuff from the latest and previous APIs, as well as from Extras, but am still getting the same error.
The app is just a simple app aimed at phones, so I didn~t install wear or tv libraries.
How far back do I have to go with Android APIs?
And is there anything that I should install that isn't obvious?

There are a lot of answers out there already for this particular error, but many of them are vague, and don't give exact instructions, or refer to components that I don't recognise, I think because I am using Xamarin.

Here is my theme code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.my_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item> <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item> <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Here is the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="My_app.My_app">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
    <application android:label="My_app" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.my_theme" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the Android manager showing what is installed.  Is there something obvious that is not installed?

[image: androidmanager1]
[image: androidmanager2]
[image: androidmanager3]
[image: androidmanager4]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `@android:style/Theme.my_theme` is pointing to a resource named `Theme.my_theme` within the `android` namespace instead of your local app package.

Change `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.myTheme"` to `android:theme="@style/Theme.myTheme"` to fix the error.

Comment: Yes, it did the trick.  I hadn't realised that @style was for locally defined stuff.  THANK YOU.